# How to map a calculated value to a property?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, calculated-columns

I'm using Entity Framework to map database to a class in my application.
The class is automatically generated as partial class by EF and I also added some other properties in my own file to the same partial class.

I use these queries to get a list of entities from the table (they are equivalent as far as I can tell):

```
db.DailyEntry.ToList  
db.DailyEntry.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM DailyEntry").ToList  
db.Database.SqlQuery(Of DailyEntry)("SELECT DailyEntry.DailyEntryId, DailyEntry.Driver, DailyEntry.Billing, DailyEntry.EntryDate FROM DailyEntry").ToList
```

I then added a field to this class:

```
Public Property IsHoliday As Boolean = False
```

I iterated through the list and calculated whether the date falls on a bank holiday. I have a database table of holidays:

```
For Each entry As DailyEntry in _myList_
    entry.IsHoliday = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of Boolean)("SELECT IsHoliday FROM Holiday WHERE HolidayDate = {0}", entry.EntryDate).FirstOrDefault  
Next
```

This all works fine but as the amount of records increased, so did the number of database calls and I need to speed the application up by merging these into a single call.
I modified the query to include the holiday info:

```
SELECT DailyEntry.*, Holiday.IsHoliday AS IsHoliday FROM DailyEntry LEFT OUTER JOIN Holiday ON DailyEntry.EntryDate = Holiday.HolidayDate;
```

or

```
SELECT DailyEntry.DailyEntryId, DailyEntry.Driver, DailyEntry.Billing, DailyEntry.EntryDate, Holiday.IsHoliday AS IsHoliday FROM DailyEntry LEFT OUTER JOIN Holiday ON DailyEntry.EntryDate = Holiday.HolidayDate;
```

and a few similar tries. They work well when I test them as queries on the database and return expected data, but when I try to use them in my app:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery(Of DailyEntry)("SELECT DailyEntry.*, Holiday.IsHoliday AS IsHoliday FROM DailyEntry LEFT OUTER JOIN Holiday ON DailyEntry.EntryDate = Holiday.HolidayDate").ToList
```

the IsHoliday property is always left at default value (False).

Is there a way to get these calculated columns that are not part of the original database table to map to my properties?

Thanks in advance,
Zdenek

Comment: Does the column "IsHoliday" exist in your database ?

Comment: Not on the DailyEntry table.  
It is a column from a different table (Holiday).

Comment: Just to make sure the table holiday had a IsHoliday column IN YOUR DATABASE. Seconde problem is `IsHoliday As Boolean = False ` what if you remove the `= false` ?

Comment: Yes, IsHoliday is a bit column in my table Holiday.  
Not sure what you mean by the second part. It is False because that's the default for Boolean in VB.net as I understand it. It is not initialized at this point, though I did try it with setting the value as well. I also tried to make it Nullable(Of Boolean), the default value was Nothing.

Comment: if your holiday table is correctly populated, i mean there are some `true` values in your bit column... this should work

Comment: It is a more general problem, not specific to the boolean value. I can just add a string to return as ExtraComment in this way (query on database works: [https://i.imgur.com/GJEW7xR.png], but when I run it in my application, the ExtraComment (which is a property defined outside the EF) isn't assigned the value: [https://i.imgur.com/hRI8lEI.png]

Comment: Is it database first code ? in this case you have to update your .EDMX file, open this file, right click in the white void and choose update from database.

Comment: Yes, it is database first, but the "extra" properties (such as IsHoliday for DailyEntry or ExtraComment) are not part of the database tables, only the .net class. I don't really want to add the column to the DailyEntry database table. It isn't a big deal here (although it would denormalize the database a bit), but I'd like a similar functionality at other places.

Comment: Ha i see, no you can't call a fully VB coded variable or calculation inside a select query... How does it even worked in your database ? Do you also have a calculated field in your db ? if it's the case you will have to call a stored procedure instead... Or map the calculated field but i never succeeded doing the second option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161473/discussion-between-meiffert-and-antoine-pelletier).